# Как перемешать слова в строке php

Tags: массивы, php, строки

Помогите решить задачу. Есть строка, допустим: "Бондаренко Николай Петрович".
Нужен массив, в котором слова данной строки будут чередоваться. 
Для примера:

- Бондаренко Николай Петрович
- Бондаренко Петрович Николай
- Николай Бондаренко Петрович
- Николай Петрович Бондаренко
- Петрович Николай Бондаренко
- Петрович Бондаренко Николай

Только есть один момент, что строка может состоять не только из трех слов (может и два слова, а может и пять). Т.е. нужны все варианты чередования слов.

Comment: 1. Разбиваем строку на слова (`preg_split('\s+', $str);`).
2. Составляем все возможные комбинации.

Comment: 1. сделать из строки массив отдельных слов [`explode(" ")`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php);
 2. узнать длину массива — `count()`;
 3. рекурсивный алгоритм перебора: в левой позиции должен побывать каждый из элементов, для следующей позиции должен побывать каждый, кроме использованных левее.

Comment: @cheh1, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Классический пример:

`http://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/php-cookbook/1565926811/ch04s26.html`

```
function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    if (empty($items)) { 
        print join(' ', $perms) . "\n";
    }  else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
         }
    }
}
```

Работает: `http://ideone.com/FPwele`